# Apply condition on one to many relationship in entity framwork

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two objects with one to many relationship. I want to apply condition on second collections of object. Below is my code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
IQueryable<DB.ProductionDB.CDCPortalApplicant> applicant = 
    from app in productionEntities.CDCPortalApplicant.Include("CDCPortalUnit")
    where app.FirstName == firstName 
       && app.LastName == lastName 
       && app.EmailAddress == emailAddress 
       && app.Created > date 
       && app.CDCPortalUnit.PropertyId == propertyId
    select app;
```

Here CDCPortalUnit has more than one object for CDCPortalApplicant object

```
app.CDCPortalUnit.PropertyId == propertyId
```

Actually I want to retrieve the CDCPortalApplicant object based properyID which is available in CDCPortalUnit object. CDCPortalApplicant object have multiple instance of CDCPortalUnit object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the structure of your CDCPortalUnit entity.

You can change this line

`&& app.CDCPortalUnit.PropertyId == propertyId`

To

`&& app.CDCPortalUnit.Single(portalUnit => portalUnit.SomeProperty == someValue).PropertyId == propertyId`

Comment: .Single is not available.